# Advantage and disadvantages of excluding sensitive data in the connection string?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dataset, datasource

I am always having a second thought here. I prefer to chose `No` simply because it says that it is a sensitive data but left wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages specifically of choosing this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the "advantage" of storing sensitive data in the connection string is simply that you do not need to care to set-it up in code, so it is more simple. Whether this is acceptable or not, it depends on the security needs of your application: how much you care if someone gets the password of your database?

According to  [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc716760(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Be aware that logon information and passwords may be visible in a memory dump.
>   **When data source logon and password information is supplied in the
>   connection string, this information is maintained in memory until
>   garbage collection reclaims the resources.** This makes it impossible to
>   determine when a password string is no longer in memory. If an
>   application crashes, a memory dump file may contain sensitive security
>   information, and the user running the application and any user with
>   administrative access to the computer can view the memory dump file.
>   Use Windows Authentication for connections to Microsoft SQL Server.